# Send Push notifications by FCM - Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on application in which i want to send push notifications to specific user

I got his token, store it.

Also got my API key.

I tried to send POST request with postman and it did it successfully, i want to do it programmatically in my code

```
private void notif(){
String json = "{\"to\": \"<USER_FCM>\",\"notification\": {\"title\": \"Check this Mobile (title)\",\"body\": \"Rich Notification testing (body)\"}";

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


try {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
    StringEntity params =new StringEntity("details={\"name\":\"myname\",\"age\":\"20\"} ", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.addHeader("Authorization","key=<API_KEY>");
    request.setEntity(params);
    HttpResponse response;
    response = httpClient.execute(request);
    String test = response.getEntity().getContent().toString();
    Log.d("RESPONSESS",test);

}catch (Exception ex) {

} finally {
    try {
        httpClient.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us what you have tried in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I send the push notification to a specific mobile token. I hope it helps,

```
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    
            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\r\n   \"to\" : \""+mobileToken+"\",\r\n   \"data\" : {\r\n     \"Action\" : \"on\"\r\n   }\r\n } ");
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
                    .method("POST", body)
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "key=AuthKEY")
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .build();
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t1.start();
```

Dependancy,

```
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.30.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:3.3.0'
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me 
ps: its `OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();` not `OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();` 
also i added dependancy `implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:3.3.0'` it was required

Comment: Updated the answer according to your feedback!.